# tkinter radio button text wrap

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a radio button using Tkinter as following:

```
rad1 = Radiobutton(bottomFrame, wraplength = 500, text= 'abc', value='A', variable=selected, command = lambda : clicked())
```

and got following wrap length error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/ttk.py", line 1054, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::radiobutton", kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/ttk.py", line 559, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-wraplength"
```

Comment: What's the question? The error seems pretty clear to me. ttk radiobuttons don't have a `wraplength` option, just as it says.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it depends on your python version.

> Try to replace **wraplenght** by **wrap**

Comment: (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-wrap"

Comment: Could you please send a proper code where you use this ? Your python version may be useful too

Comment: python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55)

Comment: import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Welcome to NAP")


lbl = Label(window, text = questions)
 
rad1 = Radiobutton(window,text= 'A text', wraplength = 150, value='A', variable=selected)
 
rad2 = Radiobutton(window,text= 'B text', wraplength = 150, value='B', variable=selected)
 

lbl.pack(fill = X)

rad1.pack(fill = X)
 
rad2.pack(fill = X)

window.mainloop()

Comment: Found out the the problem is with the way I imported the tkinter. It works if I use

Comment: import tkinter as tk but not work if I use "from tkinter import *"

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, wraplength (spelling...) is a valid option for Text